# Can an individual RadGrid row be selectable based upon a condition?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, selection, radgrid

I have a RadGrid that has a GridClientSelectColumn.  I have the AllowRowSelection setting set to true.  Is there a way on the server end that I can conditionally set whether an individual datarow in selectable or not?  I want some rows to be selectable on the client-side, but not others.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [blog post](http://www.myviewstate.net/blog/post/2010/01/07/Conditional-Client-side-Row-Selection-with-the-RadGrid-for-ASPNET-AJAX.aspx) on this subject to learn how to implement conditional client-side row selection with the RadGrid for ASP.NET AJAX.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you can easily accomplish that by setting a single property, but alternatively you could attach events to the onclick of the rows in question to cancel events/event bubbling so that the Row Selection event never fires.

Comment: And by attach events I mean attach them on the client side to the TRs or whichever elements the RadGrid represents rows with

Comment: I have tried that.  If I try that and click the checkbox in the header of that column, the rows act accordingly, but the header checkbox is never checked.  I think it only is checked if all its "child" checkboxes are also checked.

Comment: Hmm, then it sounds like you'd have to override the behaviour of the header checkbox as well. I know that Telerik's RadControls ship with JQuery. Have you considered assigning classes to your rows to represent "selectable" and "unselectable" and using JQuery to manipulate them & their events in a batch?